# Disable Orientation while running the camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation

I want to disable the orientation changes from portrait to landscape change while camera and photo gallery running in android. I am searching through the google but there is no use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

or

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this on your camera activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```